# Anaconda Installs with no Prompt, Navigator - Windows 10

Tags: installation, anaconda

I am having a recurring issue with install on the latest Anaconda distribution for Windows 10, 64-Bit. I have uninstalled and reinstalled 4 times. I am returned no errors from the installer. I have deleted and downloaded the installer 3 times. I go to the install location (C:) and it seems that the majority of the folders are missing (no Scripts folder,) there is no Navigator Executable, there is no Prompt executable, and the command line cannot find anything Conda. The install location is added to path.

I am installing for All Users with the Path option allowed as Admin. I have not been able to find anything online regarding what appears to be a complete failure to install. Troubleshooting for Navigator involves the Prompt, and for the Prompt involves having the Navigator.

At wits' end here. This started with a failed Django install (Conda Distribution) that managed to cascade to SSL errors and a corrupt DLL File. I used Windows to uninstall all Anaconda and Python and then manually removed the remaining libraries.